# Disconnected Event registration and subscription

Tags: c#, .net, events

The publisher exposes an event to which multiple subscribers can hook up to

on subscriber side -> publisher.OnSomeEvent += subscriber.CallMe()

Later the subscriber subscribes based on some dynamic arguments

publisher.Subscribe(arguments)

publisher.Unsubscribe(arguments)

Depending on what arguments are passed by the subscriber, I want publisher to update subscribers for the content they have subscribed.

Internally i can maintain a map of subscriber to arguments but my problem is that as event registration and subscription are disconnected i can't find a good way to pass the callee handle (so i can maintain a map subscriber->arguments) when calling Subscribe/Unsubscribe call.

To keep my API simple i don't want callee to pass "this", also as StackFrame and diagnostics API does not work in release mode because of inlining issue, i can't think of a better design.

Appreciate your help if you can suggest a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but you could have the publisher deal with the subscriber through an interface which would decouple the publisher from needing to know about any specific subscriber implementation.

For example

```
interface ISubscriber
{
object Arguments{get;}
}
```

Which would make the client API signature:

```
void Subscribe(ISubscriber subscriber)
```

Of course you may want to implement the interface on a seperate type if you don't want your subscriber types having an Arguments property.

Comment: Thanks but my idea is to make the API clean, I don't see much difference if i pass Subscribe(this) from what you mentioned. The way i am thinking of dealing with this problem is by giving functors to the subscribed clients

Comment: In subscribed client maybe i can do something like publisher.GetNewInstance - the publisher then gives a functor and internally on the publisher side i can maintain a static caching and hook up to the instance returned. Hope i make sense

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the publications, I say ditch the event and instead use something like

```
publisher.Subscribe(arguments, subscriber.CallMe)
```

To unsubscribe you must have some dort of identifier, could be a GUID, string, int, `this` (not sure why you want to avoid it)...